# Python combine data based on duplicate values in a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with data similar to what is below

```
{'Bldg1':[('0', 'Sam'), ('0', 'John'), ('1', 'Tom'), ('2', 'Jane')], 'Bldg2' :[('0', 'Peter'), ('0', 'Dan'), ('1', 'Tom'), ('1', 'Jack'), ('3', 'Frank')]}
```

I am trying to combine tenants on the same floor of a building. Except for the Tenant, there is duplicate  data like floor '0' in 'Blgd1' . I am trying take the duplicate data and combine the second value to look similar to the output below:

```
{'Bldg1':[('0', 'Sam - John'), ('1', 'Tom'), ('2', 'Jane')], 'Bldg2' :[('0', 'Peter - Dan'), ('1', 'Tom - Jack'), ('3', 'Frank')]}
```

I have been working with the function below and it will remove duplicate entries, but I am stuck moving forward. Is this even possible?

```
 def get_tenants_bldg_floor(dct, building, floor):
    unique_tenant_list = []
    for k,v in dct.iteritems():
        building = k
        for item in v:
            floor = item[0]
            tenant = item[1]
            ten_bldg_floor = tenant+', '+bldg_in_func+', '+floor_in_func
            for v in k:
                if ten_bldg_floor in unique_tenant_list:
                    print 1
                else:
                    unique_tenant_list.append(ten_bldg_floor)
                    print 0
    return unique_tenant_list
```

Comment: what are the purpose of the function inputs "building" and "floor"? I also don't understand what you mean by duplicate data. Could you add more details?

Comment: I originally pasted wrong function. Building and floor are variables from inside the function - I was told I could do this by a mentor. The duplicate data is building and floor. I am trying to combine tenants on the same floor of a building.

Comment: @Waitkus what do you mean "stuck"? What does your code do, and what does it not do? Of course it's possible, but other data structures may make it easier - how about `{building: {floor: [tenant, list]}}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I mean stuck as I dont know where to go from here. What my code does is it imports data from several CSV files to get me to data that will be used to correlate tenants to building and floor. With the current structure, it will make the list 3-4 times as big as it needs to be which is why I am trying to reduce. The dictionary you propose is perfect but I am not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do as @jonrsharpe suggests and combine the floors into a dictionary. That makes it MUCH easier to deal with, too:

```
original_data = {'Bldg1':[('0', 'Sam'), ('0', 'John'), ('1', 'Tom'), ('2', 'Jane')], 'Bldg2' :[('0', 'Peter'), ('0', 'Dan'), ('1', 'Tom'), ('1', 'Jack'), ('3', 'Frank')]}

def combine_by_floor(data):
    new_data = dict()
    for building, floortenants in data.items():
        for floor,tenant in floortenants:
            new_data.setdefault(building, {}).setdefault(floor, []).append(tenant)
    return new_data

combined = combine_by_floor(original_data)
### EXAMPLE ###
>>> print(combined)
{'Bldg1': {'2': ['Jane'], '1': ['Tom'], '0': ['Sam', 'John']}, 'Bldg2': {'3': ['Frank'], '1': ['Tom', 'Jack'], '0': ['Peter', 'Dan']}}
```

Basically, run through your dictionary, and make a new one. For each tuple, append `tenant` to `new_data[building][floor]`. If `new_data[building]` does not exist, create it as an empty dict. If `new_data[building][floor]` does not exist, create it as an empty list.

Comment: In the new dictionary, the building is the key, the floor is the value and what does the tenant become if i wanted to reference them?
for k,v in dct.iteritems():
 bldg_name = k
 for item in v:
  floor = item

Comment: @Waitkus: in the new dictionary, the key is the building, and the value is ANOTHER DICTIONARY, whose keys are floors and whose values are tenants. In other words: `for bldg, floortenants in dct.items(): for floor, tenants in floortenants.items():`